# Why did Nia transfer and absorb Conner's mother's powers in the scene at the hospital?

Tags: plot-explanation, code-8

In the movie, *Code 8*, Connor's mother was hospitalized after fainting at home. The doctor explained to Connor that a brain tumor is causing her to lose control of her powers, which is the ability to freeze things. In every manifestation of her freezing powers, blue spots and veins had appeared on Connor's mother's skin.

In a later scene, Connor brought Nia to the hospital where he coerced her to heal his bedridden mother after pulling out a pistol. Nia begun her process of healing and the very same blue spots and veins appeared on her face.

My understanding of Nia's powers is that she is able to transfer wounds (or any bodily damage) from one person and inflict them onto herself. That person gets healed while Nia suffers from those wounds in the end. Why did Nia transfer and absorb the freezing powers instead of the brain tumor? Wouldn't it make sense if she showed signs of a throbbing headache and not absorb the freezing powers? There was no indication throughout the movie that one's powers is transferable.

Answer (score 1):

After watching the movie I come to the following conclusion.

Nia did not want to die. Transferring the tumor from the Connor's mother would almost for sure kill Nia. So, she decided to stretch the healing time (and by that live a few minutes or even just moments more) by first absorbing the *blue veins* wounds. But she got lucky, while she was absorbing the *blue veins* wounds Connor changed his minds and asked Nia to stop the healing (damage transferring).

So, the scene makes viewer being strained while coming to the moment when Nia will start having the throbbing in the head. And now when the strain at its most Conor's mind changing makes a very sensual plot twist causing emotions by abruptly removing the strain the viewer previously has had.